# Inconsistent behaviour when latex printing inherited sympy classes in ipython

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

I want to override the `__str__` attribute of SymPy objects; however, I find confusing behaviour. I begin with this MWE:

```
from sympy.core.numbers import One
from sympy import Basic

class MyOne(One):
    def __str__(self):
        return "This isn't one"
    __repr__ = __str__    

class MyBasic(Basic):
    def __str__(self):
        return "This isn't basic"
    __repr__ = __str__
```

My environment is `ipython qtconsole` with

```
import sympy
sympy.init_session()
```

I find inconsistent behaviour:

```
In[]: MyOne()
Out[]: 1 
In[]: MyBasic()
Out[] Thisisn'tbasic
```

Both results appear latexed. The first result - 1 - was unexpected. I expected Thisisn'tone, as in my `__str__` function. The results of `str` and `repr` are as expected. What's going on? What does `display` actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init_session` (as well as `init_printing`) enables the SymPy LaTeX printers. You need to override the `_latex(self, printer)` method if you want to define a LaTeX string to be printed (see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html).

The reason you see your behavior is that `One` has a LaTeX printer defined, so its subclass uses that. `Basic` does not, so it falls back to the `__str__` method.

Comment: Thanks, so the doc you link to is kinda misleading, because in the example they do `# Override the __str__ method of to use CustromStrPrinter` then 
`Basic.__str__ = lambda self: CustomStrPrinter().doprint(self)`

Comment: Overriding __str__ won't work in general, only for Basic as it has no _print attribute.

Comment: Also, if possible, can you explain why sympy uses a new _print attribute? Why not just the usual `__str__`?

Comment: SymPy has many different printers. Furthermore, the printer methods pass in the printer for printing the children. This lets you customize printing by using a custom printer subclass. See the doc page I linked to for more info.